# VTD-XML produces "XML not terminated properly" error when parsing KML file

Tags: java, android, xml, vtd-xml

I'm getting a KML file containing shuttle routes and positions from my school's shuttle tracking server. I want to parse this KML in my Android application, but when I pass the file into the VTD-XML 2.9 parser, it fails, telling me that the XML is not properly terminated. I ran the file through a schema validator and although it doesn't conform to the [KML 2.1 Schema](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml21.xsd) (doesn't like the folder element), it is well-formed.

I don't think there's anything else wrong with the document, but I also don't see where there could be a problem with my code:

```
byte[] doc = new byte[32000];
URL url = new URL("http://shuttles.rpi.edu/displays/netlink.kml");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
is.read(doc);

VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(doc);
vg.parse(true);
```

Comment: it appears that the file contains an invalid character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the case that

```
is.read(doc);
```

only get you an arbitrary number of bytes, but definitely not the entire document...
you can verify that by printing out the returned value

```
int k = is.read(doc)
```

After reading the entire document, you should use setDoc(doc, 0, length), 0 is the starting offset wrt to the doc, length is length of xml document.

Comment: It's reading the entire document. The error is occurring on the newline after </Folder> and the read function is returning the correct length.

Comment: I have no problem processing the file after downloading it to the hard drive... is.read(doc) returns about 20 bytes using the code you provided...it got to be an HttP related issue, can you wrapping the read in a while loop to guarantee the entire doc is read?

Comment: Just used a while loop to read the data into the byte array, then used a FileOutputStream to send it out to a file. Did a diff on the KML I downloaded from the server and that output. There is no difference between the two, yet I still get the error. I should note that I am running the code on Android though.

Comment: is there any droit SDK for eclipse that I can download?

Comment: assuming that you use a while loop to read everything in, you then will have the total length of the XML, you should call <code>setDoc(doc,0,length)</code>

Comment: next release (very soon) will have this feature added so calling parseHttpURL will work even fixedcontentlength returns -1